# Error in building of Qt-generated iOS project in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, qt

I have generated iOS project (a Hello World project for device) using Qt. I can build and run it on device from Qt but when I open it in Xcode and click run, it tries to build for a few seconds, but then says “Cancelled” and gives no error. Nothing but says: “Build: Cancelled”. Why do I get this kind of error? Where should I check?

Some say that “Cancelled” error is related with 3rd party tools like “agvtool”. When they remove it, they successfully build and run. I tried this, when I remove “Qt” from targets, I can run the app. But this only works for Hello World project in which I havent used any of Qt-dependent classes/functions. Because I am planning to use them, I guess I need that Qt target.

Is there any solution to run in Xcode? What may cause this error?

PS:

When I check build logs, I see that each time I build, the output changes. (I run the app even if build stops again and again, each time it may give different log. Also, sometimes it runs with success.)

Here is the link for the build logs:

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_sqVuPjN726RXAxRkQxNnFoX0E&usp=sharing

Comment: My first guess is to set the computer's date to the correct value. It seems that you are still in 2013.

Comment: It worked. Interesting.